# Files are being temporarily uploaded to /root/tmp instead of /tmp

Tags: php, apache, configuration, upload

I have a simple upload form, here're the start and end tags:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

I am getting a 500 Internal Server error on submit. And apache logs show the following entries (hostname and ip redacted):

```
[Tue Feb 14 00:08:32 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ModSecurity: Input filter: Failed to create temporary file: /root/tmp/20120214-000832-TznsTkPj2kkAAE5LYREAAAAB-request_body-xqZDkt [hostname "xxxxxxxxxx.com"] [uri "/app/221/product/post.php"] [unique_id "TznsTkPj2kkAAE5LYREAAAAB"]
[Tue Feb 14 00:08:37 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ModSecurity: Input filter: Failed to delete temporary file: /root/tmp/20120214-000832-TznsTkPj2kkAAE5LYREAAAAB-request_body-xqZDkt [hostname "xxxxxxxxxx.com"] [uri "/app/221/product/post.php"] [unique_id "TznsTkPj2kkAAE5LYREAAAAB"]
```

I have searched the code, there's no mention of `root` or `upload_tmp_dir` anywhere. All code files belong to the application user and group. In `php.ini`, `upload_tmp_dir` was not initially set, I've now set it to `/tmp` but that hasn't resolved the issue either.

Any idea why it's trying to upload to `/root/tmp`?

Comment: set the right path in php.ini, then restart appache.

Comment: Is your path.ini file referring to a relative path or an absolute path?  Is your apache being run by `root`?

Comment: @Tim: it's set to `/tmp` - that's absolute, correct? Also, apache is run as `nobody` user.

Comment: Have you tried to double check the value before processing the upload?  `var_dump(ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'));`  [Looks like](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) the global php.ini is the only place you can set that value.

Comment: @quickshiftin `string(5) "/tmp/"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should check your [ModSecurity settings](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/06-special_features.html), in particular the **SecUploadDir** setting.

> File upload support
>
> ModSecurity is capable of intercepting files uploaded through POST
>   requests and multipart/form-data encoding or (as of 1.9) through PUT
>   requests.

Since there's only one place you can set that value in PHP, and it's been verified at runtime, plus we know you have ModSecurity running from the log output, seems like that's probly it.

Notes per OP:

> If you don't set the SecUploadDir parameter, ModSecurity does not
>   ignore it. So we made the following changes: SecUploadDir /tmp
>   SecTmpDir /tmp and now it works perfectly.

One other thing I stumbled upon you can try in a situation like this would be to disable mod security entirely to see if that eliminates the problem.  Then you can narrow the issue down to mod security quickly:

https://serverfault.com/questions/57210/disable-modsecurity-for-a-specific-directory

Comment: `grep SecUploadDir /etc/httpd/conf/*` and `grep SecUploadDir /etc/httpd/conf/modsec2/*` yields nothing. Good thinking though...

Comment: `grep root /etc/httpd/conf/* | grep -vE '(SecRule|author)'` doesn't show anything helpful either.

Comment: Is [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) set?  You might also circumvent it by `upload_tmp_dir = ./tmp/` in php.ini; the webserver user should be able to write files to its home directory.

Comment: open_basedir is not set. I will try the `./tmp/` solution if I can't find any other solution in a while.

Comment: Turns it was ModSecurity after all. If you don't set the `SecUploadDir` parameter, ModSecurity does not ignore it. So we made the following changes: `SecUploadDir /tmp` `SecTmpDir /tmp` and now it works perfectly. If possible, please update your answer. And thanks!

Comment: Ha, I was even going to suggest disabling it entirely to see if in the absence of SecUploadDir being set explicitly, something was still going on.  I'll update my answer.